# Проблема с размерностью при создании ResNet Keras conv1d

Tags: python, машинное-обучение, нейронные-сети, keras

Пытаюсь реализовать архитектуру ResNet в Keras. Есть много гайдов для двумерного случая conv2d, но меня интересует одномерный conv1d.

У меня есть следующая проблема:

```
c71=Conv1D(filters=128, kernel_size=3, activation='relu', padding='same')(a6)
c72=Conv1D(filters=128, kernel_size=3, activation='relu', padding='same')(c71)
sum7 = Add()([c72, a6])
a7 = Activation("relu")(sum7)
#256
c81=Conv1D(filters=256, kernel_size=3, activation='relu', padding='same')(a7)
c82=Conv1D(filters=256, kernel_size=3, activation='relu', padding='same')(c81)
sum8 = Add()([c82, a7]) #ПРОБЛЕМА ЗДЕСЬ
a8 = Activation("relu")(sum8)
```

Когда я хочу поменять количество фильтров в слое свертки(увеличить), как это описывается в архитектуре ResNet и просуммировать с предыдущим слоем старой размерности, то логично, что получаю ошибку. Тем не менее, не могу понять как решить эту проблему, хоть и посветил много времени на поиск информации. Насколько я понимаю, нужно каким-то образом увеличить размерность слоя предыдщуий свертки(у меня это a7), чтобы размерности a7 и c82 совпадали(были не 128 и 256, а 256 и 256). Но не знаю как это сделать.

Comment: Я бы наоборот попробовал уменьшить размерность большего слоя через `MaxPooling1D`. Так то там есть и `UpSampling1D` если что. Но обычно всё же пулинг делают вроде в нейросетях.

Comment: @CrazyElf, у меня размерность 60x128 и 60x256. MaxPooling1D изменяет число 60, которое изначально является количеством входных признаков и его мне трогать не надо.